# Postman csv data input into body variable

Tags: json, csv, post, postman

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
MIN(ADM_KOD)
389021
422789
311111
682144
```

And I need these values to run in a postman runner (iterations of post request) from the file to the raw json body variable -> so each iteration would post body like this..

1st iteration:

```
{
    "identifikatorSluzby": "S6163",
    "typSubjektu": "FO",
    "kodAdresnihoMista": "389021"
}
```

2nd iteration:

```
{
    "identifikatorSluzby": "S6163",
    "typSubjektu": "FO",
    "kodAdresnihoMista": "422789"
}
```

So far I have sth like this:

```
{
    "identifikatorSluzby": "S6163",
    "typSubjektu": "FO",
    "kodAdresnihoMista": "{{MIN(ADM_KOD)}}"
}
```

But its's not working. Am I missing sth?
What else I have to do to make it work?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Have you followed the examples here, https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/?

Comment: Yes, I have - finally I found mistakes I made - first one was that I didnt save the request in postman and it was empty in runner, second was brackets in variable name. Now its working... Thanks for the link again - I went throught it again and it helped a lot! :)